# I am trying to position 2 elements near the bottom in the centre of my one page website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position 2 elements near the bottom of my one page website, I have tried using bootstrap containers but this positions them at the very top of the parent element which is my background image and I can't move them down into the centre.

I have also tried position absolute but for some reason when I use percentages to position (as I want my page to be responsive), the elements are in the correct place in relation to the left and right of the screen but they will not seem to position them selves over the div image at the bottom of my multiple section page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An example of the markup, or even better, a JSFiddle would be marvelous.

Comment: Hanlet is right, we really need to see **something**. What is the main content of the page, html-wise, exactly? Try posting what you tried. Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have actually answered my own question by adding a row above the row I am trying to centre and just putting an empty div in the place of the first row with a width and height in percentages.

Answer (score 0):

**Imogen Adams**, Hi there. To center and place a div that holds 2 divs near the bottom of a image and have them over lay the image.
You can use this...

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;  
}
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLoew9d2/)** to get you started.

[image]